# Drop a column which is a subset of any other column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below. How can I drop any column which is a subset of any of the remaining columns? I would like to do this without using fillna.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ [1,1,3,3], [np.NaN,2,np.NaN,4]], columns=['A','B','C','D'] )

df
     A  B    C  D
0  1.0  1  3.0  3
1  NaN  2  NaN  4
```

I can identify here that column A is subset of B and column C is a subset of D with something like this:

```
if all(df[A][df[A].notnull()].isin(df[B]))
```

I could run a loop over all columns and drop the subset columns. But is there a more efficient way to accomplish this, so that I have the following result:

```
df
   B  D
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @BradSolomon, by subset, I mean if  'all' values of column X are present in any other column (irrespective of whether its left or right of it), then drop X. Sorry, I am realizing that the title of OP is confusing, I will recitify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still requires iteration, but you can use this list comprehension (with an if statement similar to the one you provided) to get columns to keep:

```
keep_cols = [x for x in df if not any(df.drop(x, axis=1).apply(lambda y: df[x].dropna().isin(y).all()))]
# ['B', 'D']
```

And then use the result with `filter`:

```
df.filter(items=keep_cols)
#    B  D
# 0  1  3
# 1  2  4
```

This should be fast enough, since it still uses `apply` at its core, and seems to be safer/more efficient than dropping columns within a loop.

If you're keen on a one-line solution, of course assigning the list to a variable is an optional step:

```
df.filter(items=[x for x in df if not any(df.drop(x, axis=1).apply(lambda y: df[x].dropna().isin(y).all()))])
```

Comment: not sure what exactly is the root cause in this solution, but as a result of the above implementation, I am running into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45093074/7904019