# unable to pass through generator stack of frame.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using pandas v0.20.1. Occasionally, I run into the following issue where for some reason, my program steps into the below debug mode and fails to pass through frame.py. I am not sure if this is an issue with my client program since the same code works most of the other times without this problem. Am I missing something here? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue and insight into potential root cause would be helpful. Thank You.

```
python script.py

--Call--
> /lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py(4424)<genexpr>()
-> for i in range(len(self.columns)))
(Pdb) l
4419                        pass
4420
4421            dtype = object if self._is_mixed_type else None
4422            if axis == 0:
4423                series_gen = (self._ixs(i, axis=1)
4424 ->                           for i in range(len(self.columns)))
4425                res_index = self.columns
4426                res_columns = self.index
4427            elif axis == 1:
4428                res_index = self.index
4429                res_columns = self.columns
```

Comment: What is your code that produces the problem?

Comment: @dustin, actually, I am myself digging into the code which is a combination of several classes and multiple libraries imported. I was hoping to provide the code in my OP but I don't know where the 'call' for this generator stack is coming from. Is there a way for me to trace the calling function/code-snippet? Thanks.

Comment: @dustin, using inspect module, I traced that this issue is source as a result of the implementation of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45066706/7904019 . Not sure why though.

Comment: @D.prd the solution code from your previous question shouldn't be a problem, especially as it doesn't involve a generator. I could take a closer look if you would post the actual exception, along with more of your code preceding the line which throws the exception.